# Identifying special arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, arithmetic

$R$ is a ring of even integers with special rules for multiplication and addition. Suppose that $f : Z \to R$ is an isomorphism that is defined by $f(x) = 2x+4$.  What are the special rules for addition and multiplication?

I am given a hint that i should use $a = f(x)$ and $b=f(y)$.
Because it is an isomorphism I know that $f(x)+f(y) = f(x+y)$.  And in the end i need it to be in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  what element of $R$ corresponds to $0$ in $\Bbb Z$?  what element corresponds to $1$?  I would give them hats to keep from confusing them with elements of $\Bbb Z$.  Now since you have $0+0=0$ you need $f(0) \oplus f(0)=f(0)$ and the others.  Play with them and you can define $\oplus, \otimes$

Comment: appreciate the answer but I am trying to solve it in this format.  It is going to appear on my final exam in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Take any elements $a$ and $b$ in R, and solve $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$ to find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.  Then $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$ so add them and multiply them the normal ways to find $x + y$ and $x y$ (again, in terms of $a$ and $b$).  Then use $f$ to compute the image of those combinations back in R.